# Search *values* of scope variables in Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I set a breakpoint in my app and hit it in the chrome devtools, is there any way to search for a specific *value*?  Say I have a huge object and the variable I'm looking for isn't where I expect it.  Perhaps there should be some property that is a string of "foobar".  I expect it to be in this.attributes.name but it's not there.  Is there any way to find it without clicking through every single value in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

When your app hits the breakpoint, you can run a for loop within your object.

For example, if your object is:

```
var attributes = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
```

and you wish to find out which one of them has a value of `3`, you can run a for loop in the JavaScript console within Chrome devtools which would be similar to something like:

```
for (i in attributes) {
  if (attributes[i] === 3) {
    console.log("3 was found at " + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a one-level object, but doesn't help with a complex object with multiple nested objects and various types.